# Access Hadoop with kerberos failed

Tags: hadoop, kerberos

I install hadoop and kerberos, **but when i exec `hadoop fs -ls /`  error has bean occured.**

```
[dannil@ozcluster06 logs]$ hadoop fs -ls /
16/09/13 11:34:39 WARN ipc.Client: Exception encountered while connecting to the server : javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate    failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: GSS initiate failed [Caused by GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)]; Host Details : local host is: "localhost/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "192.168.168.46":9000;
```

i can see the datanode and namenode has start up  by `jps`

```
  20963 DataNode
  21413 SecondaryNameNode
  20474 NameNode
  22906 Jps
```

i add principal `hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX` and `HTTP/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX`,then i use `xst -norandkey -k hdfs.keytab hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX HTTP/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX` to generate a `hdfs.keytab`

```
kadmin.local:  listprincs
HTTP/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
K/M@OZ.FLEX
dannil/admin@OZ.FLEX
hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
kadmin/admin@OZ.FLEX
kadmin/changepw@OZ.FLEX
kadmin/ozcluster06@OZ.FLEX
kiprop/ozcluster06@OZ.FLEX
krbtgt/OZ.FLEX@OZ.FLEX
```

then i exec `kinit -kt /home/dannil/hadoop-2.7.1/hdfs.keytab hdfs/oz.flex`

i can see my ticket status :

```
[dannil@ozcluster06 ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: KEYRING:persistent:1000:krb_ccache_4h73plA
Default principal: hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
2016-09-13T10:47:06  2016-09-14T10:47:06  krbtgt/OZ.FLEX@OZ.FLEX
```

this is my hadoop config value:

core-site.xml:

```
fs.defaultFS=hdfs://192.168.168.46:9000
hadoop.security.authentication=kerberos
hadoop.security.authorization=true
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
dfs.replication=1
dfs.permissions=false
dfs.block.access.token.enable=true
dfs.namenode.keytab.file=/home/dannil/hadoop-2.7.1/hdfs.keytab
dfs.namenode.kerberos.principal=hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
dfs.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal=HTTP/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
dfs.secondary.namenode.keytab.file=/home/dannil/hadoop-2.7.1/hdfs.keytab
dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.principal=hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
dfs.secondary.namenode.kerberos.internal.spnego.principal=HTTP/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm=700
dfs.datanode.address=0.0.0.0:61004
dfs.datanode.http.address=0.0.0.0:61006
dfs.datanode.keytab.file=/home/dannil/hadoop-2.7.1/hdfs.keytab
dfs.datanode.kerberos.principal=hdfs/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
dfs.https.port=50470
dfs.https.address=0.0.0.0:50470
dfs.webhdfs.enabled=true
dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.principal=HTTP/oz.flex@OZ.FLEX
dfs.web.authentication.kerberos.keytab=/home/dannil/hadoop-2.7.1/hdfs.keytab
dfs.http.policy=HTTPS_ONLY
dfs.data.transfer.protection=integrity
```

How could the error occured ?  and  what i should do to solve the problem?

---

Comment: Forget about `KEYRING:` and try the default `FILE:` implementation for the ticket cache. That one works with the Hadoop "hack" of the Java implementation of the Kerberos client.

Comment: To enable Kerberos trace logs: `export HADOOP_JAAS_DEBUG=true` in environment and `-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true` in the custom Java options, cf. https://steveloughran.gitbooks.io/kerberos_and_hadoop/content/sections/secrets.html (the whole GitBook is a must-read if you really want to mess with Kerberos and Hadoop)

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to execute the command as 'hdfs' user and check
2. If that's not working then can you please confirm, whether Kerberos has been enabled in ssh config file, '/etc/ssh/sshd_config', check for the line 'KerberosAuthentication Yes' and also 'GSSAPIAuthentication Yes'. By default it would be commented out, so uncomment that and change it to yes.

And please let us know here, whether it worked out or not. So that it would be helpful for others.